# Redrawing NSView in latest Swift (Xcode 6.3)

Tags: swift, xcode6.3

How to do it? setNeedsUpdate seems to be absent, and I couldn't find any recent articles on doing it, at least, in Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your `nsview` to redraw, set its property `needsDisplay` to `true`:

```
nsview.needsDisplay = true
```

If you only need to redraw part of it, specified by a `CGRect` called `rect` for example:

```
nsview.setNeedsDisplayInRect(rect)
```